# Change Parent Window Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms Android project I want to change the Parent Window.

```
  public static object ParentWindow { get; set; }

    public App()
    {
        PCA = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientID)
          .WithRedirectUri($"msal{App.ClientID}://auth")
          .Build();

        InitializeComponent();

        DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();

        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
```

I have tried to add:

```
 EMRPage = new EMRPage();
```

but I get and error "EMRPage is a type used as a variable"

Where do I make the change to have EMRPage the ParentWindow?

Comment: `ParentWindow = new EMRPage();`

Comment: Does `ParentWindow = new EMRPage();` solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, that solved it.. but it didn't fix the underlying problem...control is not returned after the MSAL authentication request.

Comment: You can open a new thread with your code there about the question `control is not returned after the MSAL authentication request`. I added an answer to this question and can you please accept/mark it so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where do I make the change to have EMRPage the ParentWindow?

To assign a value to `ParentWindow`, you should use:

```
ParentWindow = new EMRPage();
```